# Featuretools - LookupError: Time index not found in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, featuretools

I have a input dataframe which I have split up into 3 entities based on the attributes. When I try to generate features using featuretools I get the above mentioned error

```
input dataframe in_df = ['UniqueID', 'disbursed_amount', 'asset_cost', 'ltv', 'branch_id', 'supplier_id', 'manufacturer_id', 'Current_pincode_ID', 'Date.of.Birth', 'Employment.Type', 'DisbursalDate', 'State_ID', 'Employee_code_ID', 'MobileNo_Avl_Flag', 'Aadhar_flag', 'PAN_flag', 'VoterID_flag', 'Driving_flag', 'Passport_flag', 'PERFORM_CNS.SCORE',       'PERFORM_CNS.SCORE.DESCRIPTION', 'PRI.NO.OF.ACCTS', 'PRI.ACTIVE.ACCTS',       'PRI.OVERDUE.ACCTS', 'PRI.CURRENT.BALANCE', 'PRI.SANCTIONED.AMOUNT',       'PRI.DISBURSED.AMOUNT', 'SEC.NO.OF.ACCTS', 'SEC.ACTIVE.ACCTS',       'SEC.OVERDUE.ACCTS', 'SEC.CURRENT.BALANCE', 'SEC.SANCTIONED.AMOUNT',       'SEC.DISBURSED.AMOUNT', 'PRIMARY.INSTAL.AMT', 'SEC.INSTAL.AMT',       'NEW.ACCTS.IN.LAST.SIX.MONTHS', 'DELINQUENT.ACCTS.IN.LAST.SIX.MONTHS',       'AVERAGE.ACCT.AGE', 'CREDIT.HISTORY.LENGTH', 'NO.OF_INQUIRIES',       'loan_default']
```

I have split this up into 3 entities based on the information available on the dataset:

```
cust_cols = ['UniqueID','Current_pincode_ID', 'Employment.Type', 'State_ID', 'MobileNo_Avl_Flag', 'branch_id',
             'Aadhar_flag', 'PAN_flag', 'VoterID_flag', 'Driving_flag', 'Passport_flag', 'asset_cost', 'Date.of.Birth']
customers_df = df_raw_train[cust_cols]

loan_info_cols = ['UniqueID', 'disbursed_amount', 'asset_cost', 'ltv', 'branch_id', 'supplier_id', 'manufacturer_id', 
                  'Employee_code_ID', 'loan_default', 'DisbursalDate']
loan_info_df = df_raw_train[loan_info_cols]

bureau_cols = ['UniqueID','PERFORM_CNS.SCORE', 'PERFORM_CNS.SCORE.DESCRIPTION', 'PRI.NO.OF.ACCTS', 'PRI.ACTIVE.ACCTS', 
               'PRI.OVERDUE.ACCTS', 'PRI.CURRENT.BALANCE', 'PRI.SANCTIONED.AMOUNT', 'PRI.DISBURSED.AMOUNT', 
               'SEC.NO.OF.ACCTS', 'SEC.ACTIVE.ACCTS', 'SEC.OVERDUE.ACCTS', 'SEC.CURRENT.BALANCE', 'SEC.SANCTIONED.AMOUNT',
               'SEC.DISBURSED.AMOUNT', 'PRIMARY.INSTAL.AMT', 'SEC.INSTAL.AMT', 'NEW.ACCTS.IN.LAST.SIX.MONTHS', 
               'DELINQUENT.ACCTS.IN.LAST.SIX.MONTHS', 'NO.OF_INQUIRIES']
bureau_df = df_raw_train[bureau_cols]
```

```
customers_df.set_index(['UniqueID', 'branch_id'],inplace = True, append = True)
loan_info_df.set_index(['UniqueID', 'branch_id'], inplace = True, append = True)

entities = {"customers" : (customers_df, "UniqueID", "branch_id"), "loans" : (loan_info_df, "UniqueID", "branch_id"),
            "bureau" : (bureau_df, "UniqueID")
           }
relationships = [("loans", "UniqueID", "bureau", "UniqueID"),
                 ("customers", "branch_id", "loans", "branch_id")]

feature_matrix_customers, features_defs = ft.dfs(entities=entities, relationships=relationships, target_entity="customers")
```

I am getting the error" LookupError: Time index not found in dataframe

Can someone help on why is there an error as the featuretools docs does not mention any need to specify the timeindex?

Answer (score 1):

Got this resolved by creating entity sets from dataframes.

Comment: Great! This is our recommended approach. Anyone else can read more here: https://docs.featuretools.com/loading_data/using_entitysets.html